# Ajax pass through dropdown menu value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Im trying to pass through the value of the selected dropdown menu item, using the below code I can do this using single numbers such as '1' or '2' but when I try to do with text the value is set to '0'. Any Idea's the value is needed to run a variable on another page using Ajax.

HTML PAGE ======

```
 <html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onChange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="B0012345">B0012345</option>
<option value="COM601">COM601</option>
<option value="3">ID Nothing</option>
<option value="4">ID Four</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP Page =======

```
<?php include "db.php" ?>

<?php
$q = intval($_get['q']);

echo $q;



$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, "SELECT * FROM feedback WHERE ModuleCode = '".$q."'");



echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Hometown</th>
<th>Job</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['StudentID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FeedbackID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ModuleCode'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Viewed'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['StudentComment'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";


echo "Result kk" . $row;

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: The problem is `intval()` in `$q = intval($_get['q']);` _Strings will most likely return 0 although this depends on the leftmost characters of the string._ http://in3.php.net/intval

Comment: Aren't you getting any notice for $_get varibale? You need to change that to $_GET. $_GET is a super global variable in PHP which is used to access the values pass via query strings. For more info you can go to php.net website

Comment: Thanks @Spokey Do you know what I could use instead of intval? bit of a newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you getting any notice for $_get varibale? If not then you have to enable error reporting. Since the $_get['q'] is undefined, you need to change that to `$_GET['q']`. $_GET is a super global variable in PHP which is used to access the values pass via query strings. For more info you can go to php.net website